# How to deploy multiple reactjs applications with nginx?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy multiple projects on same path.

I'm working with a virtualbox using ubuntu.
I've created a folder called multiprojects and inside there are 3 folders with one project inside eachone: **demo**, **project1** and **project2**.

- demo folder contains all files builded after call `npm run build` on demo project.
- project1 folder contains a folder, with name build, that contains all files buided after call `npm run build` on project1.
- project2 folder contains a folder, with name build, that contains all files buided after call `npm run build` on project2.

Also, project1 contains "homepage" in package.json that redirect to project1. "homepage": "/project1". 
project2 contains "homepage" in package.json that redirect to project2. "homepage": "/project2" and 
demo project doesnt contains homepage in pacakage.json

Each projeact has in App.js is own public path:

For example, in demo project has as a publicPath /demo, in project1 /project1 and finally in project2 /project2

```
const publicPath = "/demo";

return (
    translations &&
    styles && (
        <BrowserRouter basename={publicPath}>
            <ToastProvider>
                <IntlProvider
                    key={settings.locale}
                    locale={settings.locale}
                    defaultLocale="en"
                    messages={translations[settings.locale]}
                >
                    <Routes />
                </IntlProvider>
            </ToastProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
```

And this is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen  8090;
    server_name localhost;
    index index.html index.htm;

        location /project1 {
            root /home/osboxes/Documents/multiproject/project1/build;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /project2 {
            root /home/osboxes/Documents/multiproject/project2/build;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location / {
            root /home/osboxes/Documents/multiproject/demo;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

I have two questions:

- How can I do it better?
- How can do this in a docker file?

Comment: The way you're doing it now seems fine; I wouldn't even drag Docker into the picture since the output of `npm build` is just static files that a non-container Nginx can serve just fine.  Is there a specific problem you're running into?

Comment: No, only that if there is a better way to do it. Now is running in virtualbox with ubuntu and works fine.